# YA Book in which the (human?) leader of goblins is imprisoned at the bottom of a well

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I am trying to remember a book I read in elementary school, probably in the second half of the 1980s, about which I do not remember very much, probably just one chapter.

What I do recall is that it took place in a fantasy world with both humans living above ground and goblins underground.  (There may have been other races too.)  However, I think the leader of the goblins was actually a human (or at least indistinguishable from a human, unlike most of the goblins).  I don't think he was their king; he might have been a democratically-elected leader, or he might just have been the most respected elder of a tribal goblin society.

For some reason, he had been imprisoned (probably by the above-ground humans) at the bottom of a well shaft.  He might even have agreed to be imprisoned there as a hostage to guarantee the goblins' good behavior (in which case putting him at the bottom of the well was probably a way of trying to make him comfortable).  At the bottom of the shaft, there were some cave or rough-hewn chambers, which might or might not have been half-filled with water.  I think there were three or four human children who were the main characters, and they needed something that the prisoner had.  Somehow, they got it from him, but one of the kids ended up stuck at the well bottom with him and was taken out of action for an extended period of time.

I think there were a few pen-and-ink illustrations in the book, maybe including one from the chapter I am thinking of, showing the main character looking around the cave at the bottom of the well, trying to find a way out.  Eventually, the character somehow manage to find away to connect through from the well to the goblin-occupied caves and escape, although the imprisoned goblin leader may have refused to leave that way with the child—as a matter of honor, perhaps.

This was probably a hardback, and I think it had a very black cover, with just white line art and the author/title on the front.  I know the book was quite a bit longer than this, and I think it was actually rather thick for something I might have found in an elementary school library, but I just don't recall the rest.

Comment: My first thought is _[The War of the Flowers](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_War_Of_The_Flowers.html?id=cRYjgfymePYC&source=kp_book_description)_ by Tad Williams.